# How to check if an expression is empty (void)?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

What is the best way to check if a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` instance is empty? For example, something like this:

```
Expression expression = Expression.Empty();
...
if (expression.IsEmpty) { ...
```

only that `IsEmpty` does not exist.

One idea is to test the outcome of `ToString`:

```
if (expression.ToString() == "default(Void)") { ...
```

but that doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation `Empty()` returns

> A DefaultExpression that has the NodeType property equal to Default
>   and the Type property set to Void.

so you should be able to use:

```
if(expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Default && expression.Type == typeof(void))
```

Comment: But that doesn't mean that there can't ever be an expression that is a void type and a default value that represents something other than an empty expression.

Comment: That would be exactly my next question. I see the default part, but isn't testing `expression.Type == typeof(System.Void)` enough? Something cannot be emptier than the voidness itself... can it?

Comment: @Dejan That's not true.  There are all sorts of expressions that have no type.  It just means that they don't produce a value (and are therefore used for their side effects).

Comment: @Dejan - I think any block will have a type of `void`, whereas an `Empty` expression is also empty. So `() => { Console.WriteLine(); }` should also have type `void` but is not empty.

Comment: Got it! Thank you guys!